# Should one add the 4th LOR for the admit panel (PhD CS USA Fall 2022)

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science, recommendation-letter, undergraduate

**Background:** CS undergrad

I have 3 Letter Writers whom I have done in-depth research with (published, to-be published work). But I have not performed any coursework with any of them because 2 of them are outside my university and the 1 within my university is in a different department.

I have my "class advisor" whom I have done minimal research with and attended 4 of her courses (mostly programming and 1 Software Theory Class).

**Question:** Should I ask her to be my 4th Letter Writer?

Many applications say that they will allow a 4th letter but one needn't submit them. Hence the question.

[Do LOR writers need to be someone who's taught you a class?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/163424/do-lor-writers-need-to-be-someone-whos-taught-you-a-class) I am aware of the similar question here but this is specifically in regards to the 4th letter writer for course work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fourth letter will strongly support your application and is from someone who can fairly judge your work, then it would be better to send it than not. But a lukewarm letter won't help you and might dilute stronger letters. You have to judge that.

The letter readers will be looking to make a prediction of success for accepted candidates.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!